# Upgrading to 20.04, but getting "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."

Tags: apt, updates

I'm getting that error when trying to update to 20.04. I've updated, upgraded, dist-upgraded, showhold [it returns nothing]... like everything is updated and it's still telling me to update before upgrading to 20.04 [I feel like my computer is Mr. Burns saying "I thought I told you to shave off those sideburns!"] Any idea what I'm missing? Ah've updated all I can, she can'ae update noo more!

Comment: What OS & release are you currently using (you haven't said).  If you `sudo apt update`, I'd explore that output looking for issues (anything missing for example), then `sudo apt full-upgrade` again checking the output. Next I'd check you haven't put a *hold* on any packages (`apt-mark showhold`)... but the starting point is what is your current release?

Comment: Oh sorry, doing the LTS jump from 18.04 [Lubuntu]. I've done the showhold, so I know it's not that, but I did not know of full-upgrade. I always did upgrade or dist-upgrade... going to try that now!

Comment: Ok, full-upgrade doesn't do anything... says I'm all current.

Comment: apt update does give me errors on Spotify and Google Earth, saying the public key is not available. It's also giving me an error for Chrome, which is odd since I don't have Chrome but rather Chromium... maybe I can delete these and reinstall them after?

Comment: An `apt full-upgrade` (like `apt-get dist-upgrade`) should bump you from 18.04.4 to 18.04.5, but won't change the 18.04 part as that's not it's purpose.  Check your architecture is one that allows *release-upgrade* (eg. 18.04 i386 could go to 18.10, 19.04 (both now EOL) but no higher, what architecture are you running?)

Comment: You've mentioned Lubuntu, which should be installed to upgrade from 18.04 (LXDE) to any later release (LXQt) due to desktop change. In the Lubuntu release notes (https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) you'll read "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"

Comment: Ooooohhhh damnit, thank you, but oh that sucks

Comment: I never partitioned this computer to be able to fresh install without losing everything, so that's not going to work. But also one program won't work because one of it's dependencies has a bug in the 18.04 repos.... big ooooofffffffffff

Comment: [also it's x86_64... so that was never the issue]

Comment: You can re-install without wiping user data. If you use the *Manual Partitioning*, use your existing partitions & don't format any, it'll note your additional packages, erase system directories, install system, attempt to add back your additional packages (if available on new release in Ubuntu repos) then ask to reboot. It doesn't touch user data UNLESS you formatted the partition (the format option causes a CLEAN or NEW installation). Of course you should backup first (format box is easily missed). Clean install gets a better install experience, but what I've said here is an option :)

Answer (score 3):

Between 18.04 and 20.04 Lubuntu has switched desktop environments.  Lubuntu used to use LXDE but has switched to LXQt in recent releases.

Switching a DE is a huge change.  It involves changing out dozens of core packages that all must work together in harmony to give you a working desktop environment.  It's hard to account for all of the possible ways that the new software will work with all of your existing configurations for the LXDE desktop environment.

For this reason, upgrading from Lubuntu 18.04 to Lubuntu 20.04 requires a clean installation from external installation media.  The typical upgrade path is unsupported.

The [release notes for Lubuntu 20.04](https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/) state:

> Due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop
> environments, **the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04**
> or below to any greater release. **Doing so will result in a broken
> system**. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, **please
> do a fresh install**.

You can download the new version of Lubuntu at [lubuntu.me](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/).

Comment: I ended up just backing my up /home on an external HD and replacing the whole OS with Ubuntu Studio 20.04LTS. Ironically, I will have to do the same in a few years, but at least I got a heads up that Ubuntu Studio is drastically changing after this release. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the problem for a long time. (upgrade ubuntu 18 version to 20 lts)
In my case, the problem was at the stage

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

return  wine-stable winehq-stable not upgraded
solved  a problem

change file /etc/apt/sources.list
comment line (# ) line `deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/`

and  launched again

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

return not upgraded count 0

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and the upgrade process has started

Comment: Maybe you should have read the answer posted one year ago. Although what you describe isn't wrong *per se*, it isn't an answer for this question.

Comment: I have not found a solution in other threads. I originally wrote an answer for another question but could not post there. And I found the closest

Comment: This answer is not for the one who originally asked, but for those who will look for a solution to a similar problem on ubuntu =)

Comment: Not really, this answer is for YOU, i.e., for your specific problem that stemmed from adding a likely unneeded software source for Wine (it's already in the repositories). This is unlikely to help anyone else.